# Bootstrap modal won't display if the position of its parent container set to fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal which I use it as a instruction guide.

I want to fix it at the top-right corner of the viewport so I use the `fixed` position. But the modal goes grey with this setting.

If I use the `absolute` position setting, the modal display fine but it won't be fixed in mobile screens as it will shift with the zoom event.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a8Lcj7rk/

Comment: why not just fix the button instead of the whole container? the modal is not part of the position of the button

Comment: Why don't you use `popovers` component of Bootstrap for such things? They are meant to be similar approach

Comment: Do you want to simply place your `modal` on `top-right` corner? Add this code, `.modal .modal-dialog {margin-right: 0;margin-top: 6px;}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Simple solution. Just put your modal out side of your container div as I have done below.

> **Modal markup placement**
>   Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

Reference for the above is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">instruction</button>


</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Positioned elements works as layers, `.modal-backdrop` taking `z-index-1040` and your `.container` is on `z-index:0` if you want to show it above `.modal-backdrop` you need to set `z-index` of `.container` greater than `1040`, in your case `1041` or more.

```
.container {
  z-index:1041;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@jindsay All you need to do is just keep your modal outside your main data container otherwise it will effect Z-index of modal. Please have a look in following code. I hope you were expecting the same.

```css
.container {
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">instruction</button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```